# Debug/Run in vscode: Program exists

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have an express.js app.

Whenever I try to debug/run it in vscode, it just runs through and exists. How do I keep this process alive just like it normally does? Or is something wrong with my config?
No errors whatsoever are thrown.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "www",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script",
            "www"
        ],
        "address": "localhost",
        "port": 5000,
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

My npm-script looks like this:

`flow-node www/index.js`

I want to debug/run this script from vscode since I have a lot of env-variables and, obviously, for debug-reasons.

Comment: please post the js code

Comment: the js-code is not relevant. it's basically a default express.js app. it totally runs from the terminal or from the webstorm run-configuraton

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to specify the `program` attribute of the `launch.json` config.

> program - executable or file to run when launching the debugger
>   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes